# Printing datagridview fetched from a mysql database to rdlc or crystal reports in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to print the data inside a datagridview through some kind of reporting. I am using a mysql database with C# winforms.

Comment: Did you try anything? Some code examples would be great..

Comment: I am having trouble getting the data, i have gone through some tutorials which required datasets but i am unable to create a dataset because there is no support for mysql connection in the dataset wizard.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you would like to print data inside a datagridview. What makes more sense is to have the data in a datatable that you can then use as as datasource for your datagridview and your report. To create a datatable programatically see here: http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-create-datatable.html?m=1
That will overcome the lack of designer support for mysql.